# Can I pass a list to stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following list

```
ID | DESC | PRICE 
10 | SHOE | 5000
11 | LACE | 3000
12 | GAME | 2000
13 | TOAD | 3000
```

I am now passing individual rows in a foreach loop, and establishing a new connection all the time, which looks unconventional but I am hoping there is a faster way.

This is the code I have.

```
foreach(var item in tempList)
{
     using (connection)
     {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlComman("StoredProc", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id", item.id));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("desc", item.desc));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("price", item.price));
        ...
     }
}
```

So how do I pass a list to a stored procedure?

Comment: Can you please specify the version of SQL Server you are using whenever you ask a question about SQL Server? (It took a long cruise through your previous questions to determine that you are using at least SQL Server 2008.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a custom table data type in SQL Server, use that as a parameter to your stored procedure, use a DataTable in your code, and fill it with the rows.

Read more on [MSDN: Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

To give a practical example of TVPs, in addition to the links (which are definitely worthwhile reading). Assuming SQL Server 2008 or better.

First, in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Items AS TABLE
(
  ID          INT,
  Description VARCHAR(32),
  Price       INT
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure
  @Items AS dbo.Items READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable(ID, [DESC], Price)
    SELECT ID, Description, Price FROM @Items;
END
GO
```

Now in C#:

```
DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID"));
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description"));
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Price"));

foreach(var item in tempList)
{ 
    tvp.Rows.Add(item.id, item.desc, item.price); 
}

using (connection)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", tvp);
    tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Holy cow! You mean I could pass a whole `DataTable` as an `SqlParameter`?

Comment: @jp2code Yes, assuming you are on SQL Server 2008 or better and have the ability to create table types in the source database.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at using [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) to pass all the rows in one call as a single parameter:

> Table-valued parameters provide an easy way to marshal multiple rows
>   of data from a client application to SQL Server without requiring
>   multiple round trips or special server-side logic for processing the
>   data. You can use table-valued parameters to encapsulate rows of data
>   in a client application and send the data to the server in a single
>   parameterized command. The incoming data rows are stored in a table
>   variable that can then be operated on by using Transact-SQL.