# How to return all rows if IN clause has no value?

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-like, in-clause

Following is sample query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetModel
(
    @brandids varchar(100), -- brandid="1,2,3"
    @bodystyleid varchar(100) -- bodystyleid="1,2,3"

)
AS
   select * from model
   where brandid in (@brandids) -- use a UDF to return table for comma delimited string
   and bodystyleid in (@bodystyleid)
```

My requirement is that if `@brandids` or `@bodystyleid` is blank, query should return all rows for that condition.

Please guide me how to do this? Also suggest how to write this query to optimize performance.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls your stored procedure? There are some tricks for passing lists around that you may be able to take advantage of if it is being called from a .NET language.

Comment: hi jamieSee, i am using entity framwork 4.0 so i call SP the way it being called in EF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need dynamic SQL or a split function for this anyway, since `IN ('1,2,3')` is not the same as `IN (1,2,3)`.

Split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts
(
   @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT Item = CONVERT(INT, Item) FROM ( 
     SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int') FROM ( 
       SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
       + '</i>').query('.') ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)) AS y
     WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
```

Code becomes something like:

```
SELECT m.col1, m.col2 FROM dbo.model AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SplitInts(NULLIF(@brandids, ''), ',') AS br
ON m.brandid = COALESCE(br.Item, m.brandid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SplitInts(NULLIF(@bodystyleid, ''), ',') AS bs
ON m.bodystyleid = COALESCE(bs.Item, m.bodystyleid)
WHERE (NULLIF(@brandids, '') IS NULL OR br.Item IS NOT NULL)
AND (NULLIF(@bodystyleid, '') IS NULL OR bs.Item IS NOT NULL);
```

(Note that I added a lot of NULLIF handling here... if these parameters don't have a value, you should be passing NULL, not "blank".)

Dynamic SQL, which will have much less chance of leading to bad plans due to parameter sniffing, would be:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'SELECT columns FROM dbo.model
WHERE 1 = 1 '
+ COALESCE(' AND brandid IN (' + @brandids + ')', '')
+ COALESCE(' AND bodystyleid IN (' + @bodystyleid + ')', '');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Of course as @JamieCee points out, dynamic SQL *could* be vulnerable to injection, as you'll discover if you search for dynamic SQL anywhere. So if you don't trust your input, you'll want to guard against potential injection attacks. Just like you would if you were assembling ad hoc SQL inside your application code.

When you move to SQL Server 2008 or better, you should look at [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407089/61305)).

Comment: Don't do the dynamic SQL shown here, it's injection vulnerable. Go with the other suggestion and use a split function that loads the values into a temp table or table variable.

Comment: @JamieSee there is only injection vulnerability if a user is actually typing "1,2,3" into a text field on a form or something - if this input is coming from a more trusted source, there is no reason to don the tin foil hat just yet. Also, why is a temp table or table variable a requirement? Plenty of splitting solutions don't need to put results into a temporary object.

Comment: True, but we also don't know that this isn't being taken either directly from user input or being assembled from user input. In the face of unknown usage, I prefer to err on the side of caution. If non-string value types are being enforced somewhere along the chain between user and stored procedure, then I'd agree that what you propose is ok. That also means, however, that when it gets reused somewhere else, you must ensure that the behavior in the new caller is the same -- Something that I've seen dev teams fail at before.

Comment: @JamieSee I've also seen dev teams spend so much time protecting their code from malicious users that they throw performance in the toilet. The function, coalesce, or etc. add a lot of volatility to the execution plan, and dynamic SQL is easy enough to protect from unsanitized inputs anyway. Please feel free to add a more comprehensive answer if you think mine and this commentary is insufficient.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for your reply. In my case user will pass input thru checkbox so no risk of SQL injection. Now i can resolve my issue using the solution given by you. OR i can do same thing using LINQ as i am using EF4. So Performance wise which one will be best??

Comment: Personally I think using a stored procedure is better overall. I have no idea what LINQ will ultimately send to SQL Server in this case but I'm sure it won't be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(@brandids = '' or @brandids is null)
Begin
     Set @brandids = 'brandid'
End

if(@bodystyleid = '' or @bodystyleid is null)
Begin
     Set @bodystyleid = 'bodystyleid'
End

Exec('select * from model where brandid in (' + @brandids + ')
and bodystyleid in (' + @bodystyleid + ')')
```